# Can anybody identify this device?

Tags: boot-loop, tablet

I am trying to fix an Android tablet. As far as I know, it's stock, but that's about it. There is no inclination of the manufacturer.

Here are the pics:

[image: The back] [image: The front]
<sup>Back and front (click images for larger variants)</sup>

I cannot simply go to check in Settings › About device as the device is trapped in a bootloop, and the stock recovery asks foe non-existant buttons (it wants a home button. There is none. The <kbd>power</kbd> button has no effect in recovery for some reason. The device has a <kbd>power</kbd> button, <kbd>volume</kbd> and mysterious silver button-like dot, but it doesnt do anything.

-EDIT-
Got it into recovery mode, though I cannot select ANY items, just navigate:

[image: Recovery mode]

Navigating via <kbd>Vol+</kbd>/<kbd>Vol-</kbd> works, but I cannot confirm any entry: the <kbd>power</kbd> button yields no action. And though the second line in the screenshot reads "vol up/vol down, home, enter", there are no home or enter keys available. Pressing both volume rockers simultaneously only switches the screen off (can be turned on again by pressing the <kbd>Vol-</kbd> button).

-EDIT 2-
A blue light appears when I try to turn it on via LED

-EDIT 3-
Since its in a boot loop, I tried every button combo:

- <kbd>Power</kbd> on its own - normal boot loop
- <kbd>Power</kbd> +  <kbd>up</kbd> - recovery.
- All buttons (not counting silver dot, I cant press it in.) - Recovery mode.
- <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd> - normal boot loop

No combination brought me to [safe-mode](/questions/tagged/safe-mode), so I cannot check *Settings › About device* there either.

Comment: @Izzy Nah, they arent shown. Unless this crack in the thing is where they...... nope, not that either.

Comment: OK, now I'm really out of ideas. I've again integrated our latest insights with your post (and cleaned up comments) – afraid that's all I can do here. With some luck, someone figures something by the details we've collected so far. Fingers crossed!

Comment: @Izzy Aye, though I am about as hopeful as a Pokemon nuzlocke player stuck with nothing but a magikarp

Comment: @Izzy Hey man, I might be able to unscrew the back, see if there are any hints