# Will cutting the sound cables do any long term damage?

Tags: hardware, speaker

If anybody read the question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/142627/can-anybody-identify-this-device) I have now commited to dissecting the tablet completely, because SCIENCE! Anyway, only one thing is keeping the back connected to the main tablet: the two cables that connect the main motherboard to the speaker.

So, this is it:

[image: Image link]

So, to my question: will cutting these cables result in *unfixable* hardware issues. To clarify,  by *unfixable* I mean destruction of hardware e.g. cutting off power to an important segment. The obvious lack of sound is no issue to me, I can just wire it back if I want (which I won't, for personal reasons)

Comment: Also, can someone embed the image? I always break the embedding on the mobile version of stack exchange.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be fine (95%). It's nothing more than electricity. Just make sure to seal it up really well when done modifying your phone.

Comment: To downvoters: How could the answer be improved?